# Core Data object graph to XML file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm not asking for a solution, but rather what topics I should be reading for the optimal solution for this problem?

I want to read whatever I have in my object graph and write it in an xml file.

I think I can fetch every object manually, read them and then write them to a file. But I dont think this is a good approach to this problem.

Can someone be my guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [RestKit](http://restkit.org/). It is meant for talking to server from iOS devices but it also works as an app and has a very powerful object model. You can probably abuse it to serialize your object.